# What is a good way to layer like this in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.x

I've been working on a small project in pygame. It's an overhead 2D game, but if a player is behind an object, I need the player to be one layer behind it. If the player is in front of the object, it needs to be a layer ahead of it.

```
    for image, imagerect, imageypos in zip(blitimages, blitrects, blitypositions):

    if realy < imageypos:
        screen.blit(playerimage, playerimagerect)
        screen.blit(image, imagerect)
    if realy > imageypos:
        screen.blit(image, imagerect)
        screen.blit(playerimage, playerimagerect)

    if realy == imageypos:
        screen.blit(playerimage, playerimagerect)
        screen.blit(image, imagerect)
```

That is what I've tried but it does not work. It is displaying the player always in front.

For reference:

```
blitrects = [house1imagerect, house2imagerect, rock1imagerect]
blitimages = [house1image, house2image, rock1image]
blitypositions = [house1y, house2y, rock1y]
```

I am mostly in need of a way to do this correctly (that's also fast), and why this way didn't work. I am willing to post more parts of the code if needed for an answer, just post a comment saying so! Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Entire Code:

```
import sys, pygame, math, random
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 1000,720
x = 0
y = 0




house1x = 500
house1y = 360

house2x = 1470
house2y = 360


rock1x = -100
rock1y = 300


scrollx = 0
scrolly = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
counter = 0


playercollideRect =  pygame.rect.Rect((0, 0), (75, 25))

house1collideRect = pygame.rect.Rect((0, 0), (870, 605))
house2collideRect = pygame.rect.Rect((0, 0), (870, 605))

rock1collideRect = pygame.rect.Rect((0, 0), (140, 100))



collision = False


lastkey = 'down'
animationdirection = 'down'



playerimage = pygame.image.load("img/player/player0.png").convert_alpha()
playerimagerect = playerimage.get_rect()


house1image = pygame.image.load("img/structures/house1.png").convert_alpha()
house1imagerect = house1image.get_rect()

house2image = pygame.image.load("img/structures/house2.png").convert_alpha()
house2imagerect = house2image.get_rect()


rock1image = pygame.image.load("img/objects/rock1.png").convert_alpha()
rock1imagerect = rock1image.get_rect()



clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screencolor = 0, 155, 20
gamefont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 30)

playeranimationdown = ['img/player/player1.png','img/player/player0.png','img/player/player2.png','img/player/player0.png']
playeranimationup = ['img/player/playerback1.png','img/player/playerback0.png','img/player/playerback2.png','img/player/playerback0.png']
playeranimationleft = ['img/player/playerleft1.png','img/player/playerleft0.png','img/player/playerleft2.png','img/player/playerleft0.png']
playeranimationright = ['img/player/playerright1.png','img/player/playerright0.png','img/player/playerright2.png','img/player/playerright0.png']


pygame.mixer.music.load('audio/music/ambient.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(pygame.constants.USEREVENT)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
pygame.event.set_allowed([pygame.QUIT, pygame.KEYDOWN, pygame.KEYUP])

colliders = [house1collideRect, house2collideRect, rock1collideRect]
blitrects = [house1imagerect, house2imagerect, rock1imagerect]
blitimages = [house1image, house2image, rock1image]
blitypositions = [house1y, house2y, rock1y]

while 1:

    clock.tick(500)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    if y > 720-75-100:
        y = 720-75-100
        scrolly -= 1
    if y < 0+75+100:
        y = 0+75+100
        scrolly += 1
    if x > 1000-37-100:
        x=1000-37-100
        scrollx -=1
    if x < 0+37+100:
        x = 0+37+100
        scrollx +=1


    for collider in colliders:
        if playercollideRect.colliderect(collider):
            if lastkey == 'left':
                x += 1
            if lastkey == 'right':
                x -= 1
            if lastkey == 'up':
                y += 1
            if lastkey == 'down':
                y -= 1
            collision = True
        else:
            collision = False


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            y -= 1

            if not collision == True:
                playerimage = pygame.image.load(playeranimationup[int(math.floor(counter/50))]).convert_alpha()
                counter = (counter + 1) % 200
            lastkey = 'up'


        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += 1
            if not collision == True:
                playerimage = pygame.image.load(playeranimationdown[int(math.floor(counter/50))]).convert_alpha()
                counter = (counter + 1) % 200
            lastkey = 'down'


        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += 1
            if not collision == True:
                playerimage = pygame.image.load(playeranimationright[int(math.floor(counter/50))]).convert_alpha()

                counter = (counter + 1) % 200
            lastkey = 'right'

        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x -= 1

            if not collision == True:
                playerimage = pygame.image.load(playeranimationleft[int(math.floor(counter/50))]).convert_alpha()

                counter = (counter + 1) % 200
            lastkey = 'left'




    playerimagerect.centerx = x
    playerimagerect.centery = y


    house1imagerect.centerx = house1x+scrollx
    house1imagerect.centery = house1y+scrolly

    house2imagerect.centerx = house2x+scrollx
    house2imagerect.centery = house2y+scrolly

    rock1imagerect.centerx = rock1x+scrollx
    rock1imagerect.centery = rock1y+scrolly



    playercollideRect.midbottom = playerimagerect.midbottom

    house1collideRect.midbottom = house1imagerect.midbottom
    house2collideRect.midbottom = house2imagerect.midbottom

    rock1collideRect.midbottom = rock1imagerect.midbottom


    realx = x-scrollx
    realy = y-scrolly



    for image, imagerect, imageypos in zip(blitimages, blitrects, blitypositions):

        if realy < imageypos:
            screen.blit(playerimage, playerimagerect)
            screen.blit(image, imagerect)
        if realy > imageypos:
            screen.blit(image, imagerect)
            screen.blit(playerimage, playerimagerect)

        if realy == imageypos:
            screen.blit(playerimage, playerimagerect)
            screen.blit(image, imagerect)





    label = gamefont.render(str('FPS: '+str(clock.get_fps())), 1, (255,255,0))
    screen.blit(label, (50, 50))

    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.fill(screencolor)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stop working with `Surfaces` directly. Use the pygame's `Sprite` class.

Then you can simply give your Sprites a `_layer` attribute and use a [`LayeredUpdates`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) group for managing them, and the group will take care of the order of blitting.

Here's an example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))

class Actor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, group, color, layer, pos):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self._layer = layer
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, group)

group = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
Actor(group, (255, 255, 255), 0, (100, 100))
Actor(group, (255, 0, 255),   1, (110, 110))
Actor(group, (0, 255, 255),   0, (120, 120))
Actor(group, (255, 255, 0),   3, (130, 130))
Actor(group, (0, 0, 255),     2, (140, 140))

run = True
while run:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    group.update()
    group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Note how the order of the sprites is determined by the value of the `_layer` attribute.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer.  It is silly to use Pygame but ignore all of its built-in sprite and collision functions.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @sloth thanks for the answer, but is there a way to do this with Surfaces? If not I will use sprites

Comment: @sloth nevermind, this is indeed the correct answer, thanks for your help

Comment: Aha! `_layer` not `layer`. Pygame docs have burned me more than once. The source code documentation is better: [LayeredUpdates](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/89a650657e88a73b2b416315846c4371bf123120/src_py/sprite.py#L614)

Answer (score 1):

I tried with this code (it most likely works)

When the red surface is behind the green the green will overlap, that's why I've kept it a little transparent. When the red overtakes it will be blitted on the green. The code is same as you did. IDK why yours doesn't work

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

surface1 = pygame.Surface((50,50))
surface1.fill((255,0,0))

surface2 = pygame.Surface((50,50))
surface2.fill((0,255,0))
surface2.set_alpha(196)

surface1X = 0
surface1Y = 275

surface2X = 400
surface2Y = 275

x_change = 0
y_change = 0

speed = 2

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = speed

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                x_change = 0
                y_change = 0

    surface1X += x_change
    surface1Y += y_change

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    if (surface1X < surface2X):
        screen.blit(surface1, (surface1X, surface1Y))
        screen.blit(surface2, (surface2X, surface2Y))

    else:
        screen.blit(surface2, (surface2X, surface2Y))
        screen.blit(surface1, (surface1X, surface1Y))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: I have a feelings it is because I'm doing it multiple times for every sprite on the screen. I'm looking for a logical way to do it that would word, but thanks!

Comment: @Qwerty @ GLaDOS Questions should not contain entire code. Questions should contain a [mcve] which demonstrates the error or problem. Writing the entire code adds much unnecessary content which makes it harder and more cumbersome to read which reduces the chances of the question being answered. It also makes the question (and the answer) too tailored to the asker, making it less valueable to future readers than a question with [mcve] would.