# Why does my player character in pygame sometimes dissappear behind tiles, yet still move?

Tags: python, debugging, pygame

I'm fairly new to python in general (about a weeks knowledge) and I am making a fairly basic pygame with a bigger project in mind. The pygame I've written works how it should except for one thing I can't seem to figure out why it happens, and that is when I start up the game, the character is sometimes invisible. This changes from tile to tile and each time the game starts it's a different tile. Now I for the life of me can't figure out why this is happening and I was hoping somebody here might see what I can't.

Thanks in advance, here are some images.

[image: The first start up, player invisible in top left]

[image: First tile found where player is visible]

My main:

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
from os import path
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from tilemap import *

class Game:
def __init__(self):
    pg.init()
    self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
    self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
    pg.key.set_repeat(500, 100)
    self.load_data()

def load_data(self):
    game_folder = path.dirname(__file__)
    img_folder = path.join(game_folder, 'img')
    self.map = Map(path.join(game_folder, 'map.txt'))
    self.player_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, PLAYER)).convert_alpha()
    self.floor_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, FLOOR)).convert()
    self.wall_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, WALL)).convert()
    self.water_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, WATER)).convert()
    self.goal_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, GOAL)).convert()

def new(self):
    # initialize all variables and do all the setup for a new game
    self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.floors = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.water = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.goal = pg.sprite.Group()
    for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map.data):
        for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
            if tile == 'X':
                Wall(self, col, row)
            if tile == 'W':
                Water(self, col, row)
            if tile == '.':
                Floor(self, col, row)
            if tile == 'G':
                Goal(self, col, row)
            if tile == 'P':
                self.player = Player(self, col, row)
                Floor(self, col, row)

    self.camera = Camera(self.map.width, self.map.height)

def run(self):
    # game loop - set self.playing = False to end the game
    self.playing = True
    while self.playing:
        self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
        self.events()
        self.draw()
        self.update()

def quit(self):
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()

def update(self):
    # update portion of the game loop
    self.all_sprites.update()
    self.camera.update(self.player)

def draw(self):
    for sprite in self.all_sprites:
        self.screen.blit(sprite.image, self.camera.apply(sprite))
    pg.display.flip()

def events(self):
    # catch all events here
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            self.quit()
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                self.quit()
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                self.player.move(dx=-1)
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                self.player.move(dx=1)
            if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                self.player.move(dy=-1)
            if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                self.player.move(dy=1)

# create the game object
g = Game()
while True:
g.new()
g.run()
```

My settings:

```
DARKGREY = (40, 40, 40)

# game settings
WIDTH = 1280   # 16 * 64 or 32 * 32 or 64 * 16
HEIGHT = 720  # 16 * 48 or 32 * 24 or 64 * 12
FPS = 60
TITLE = "Code Avontuur"
BGCOLOR = DARKGREY

TILESIZE = 100
GRIDWIDTH = WIDTH / TILESIZE
GRIDHEIGHT = HEIGHT / TILESIZE

PLAYER = 'player.png'
WALL = 'wall.jpg'
FLOOR = 'floor.jpg'
WATER = 'water.jpg'
GOAL = 'goal.jpg'
```

My map:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XP.....X.....XWX
XXX.XX.XXX.XXXXX
XXX..X.XX..XXXXX
XXXX...X..XXXXXX
XWWWX.XX.XXWWWWX
XXXXX....XXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX......GX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

My sprites:

```
import pygame as pg
from PIL import Image
from settings import *

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, game, x, y):
    self.groups = game.all_sprites
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
    self.game = game
    self.image = game.player_img
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def move(self, dx=0, dy=0):
    if not self.collide(dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy

def collide(self, dx=0, dy=0):
    for wall in self.game.walls:
        if wall.x == self.x + dx and wall.y == self.y + dy:
            return True
    for water in self.game.water:
        if water.x == self.x +dx and water.y == self.y +dy:
            return True
    return False

def update(self):
    self.rect.x = self.x * TILESIZE
    self.rect.y = self.y * TILESIZE

class Wall(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, game, x, y):
    self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.walls
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
    self.game = game
    self.image = game.wall_img
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
    self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE

class Water(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, game, x, y):
    self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.water
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
    self.game = game
    self.image = game.water_img
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
    self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE

class Floor(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, game, x, y):
    self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.floors
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
    self.game = game
    self.image = game.floor_img
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
    self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE

class Goal(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, game, x, y):
    self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.goal
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
    self.game = game
    self.image = game.goal_img
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
    self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE
```

My map handler:

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *

class Map:
def __init__(self, filename):
    self.data = []
    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            self.data.append(line.strip())

    self.tilewidth = len(self.data[0])
    self.tileheight = len(self.data)
    self.width = self.tilewidth * TILESIZE
    self.height = self.tileheight * TILESIZE

class Camera:
def __init__(self, width, height):
    self.camera = pg.Rect(0, 0, width, height)
    self.width = width
    self.height = height

def apply(self, entity):
    return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

def update(self, target):
    x = -target.rect.x + int(WIDTH / 2)
    y = -target.rect.y + int(HEIGHT / 2)

    #Limit scrolling off map
    x = min(0, x)
    y = min(0, y)
    x = max(-(self.width - WIDTH), x)
    y = max(-(self.height - HEIGHT), y)
    self.camera = pg.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)
```

I hope anybody here can see what I cant, because I'm stuck and lost at this point.

Comment: That is a lot of code for us to look through--to much for me. Please reduce your code to a minimum that shows the problem, as explained in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is likely that you will find the problem yourself by doing this.

Comment: I am not very familiar with pygame, but maybe you want to inspect inwhich order your sprites are drawn on the buffer? Or if there is a depth parameter attached to a sprite? (in that case, you will want to set your hero to be always on top)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the order in which your sprites a drawn.

Instead of a regular `Group`, use a [`LayeredUpdates`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) group.

Then give your sprites a `_layer` property(*). This way you can control the order in which your sprites a drawn on the screen.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44585784/142637) an example.

---

Changes to your `Game` class:

```
...
def new(self):
    # initialize all variables and do all the setup for a new game
    self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates() # <<--- change here
    self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.floors = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.water = pg.sprite.Group()
    self.goal = pg.sprite.Group()
    ...
```

Changes to your `Player` class:

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = game.player_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._layer = 1 # <<--- add this line
```

---

**Edit:**

Since you don't actually use the Group for drawing, you could leave it as simple `Group` and just change your draw function to sort the sprites by layer:

```
for sprite in sorted(self.all_sprites, lambda i, s: s._layer):
    ...
```

or for Python 3:

```
for sprite in sorted(self.all_sprites, key=lambda s: s._layer):
    ...
```

---

* The documentation says `layer`, but it's actually `_layer`

Comment: That did it, it works perfect now! Thanks so much! I would like to add, that because of this, I did have to add _layer = 0 to all the wall and water 
   classes as such `class Water(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.water
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = game.water_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._layer = 0 <- THIS
        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE`

Comment: Glad I could help. Dou you store your code on github or bitbucket? If anyone could just download the running game it would be easier to answer such questions.

Comment: Havent used those before, I'll look into it for the future! Thanks so much again, I can now focus on the hardware portion that's supposed to be attached to this! (This was my first post ever on here, hope I atleast supplied enough for a regular question)