# Pygame how to change image layer using LayeredUpdates()

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm having trouble figuring out how to change the layers of images. What I try to achieve is moving a player around the screen and when it comes across an object, box, stone, etc., the player appears on top of the object when its bottom coord is bigger than the object and behind when the coord is smaller than the object. Instead it's always in front or behind the object.

I've searched online and couldn't quite get what I want and I had found a post on Stack Overflow which demonstrated the usage of `pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()`. It explained the idea but I still can't figure out how to change the image layer while running the program. A simple code demonstration would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a working example of `LayeredUpdates` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44585784/142637).

Note that the documentation of pygame is wrong: your sprites need a `_layer` attribute, not `layer`.

To actually change the layer of a sprite, you have to use the functions of `LayeredUpdates`, like [`change_layer`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.change_layer) or [`switch_layer`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.switch_layer).

Answer (score 2):

Give your objects a `self._layer` attribute and set it to the `self.rect.bottom` coord. Sprites with a higher layer number appear above the sprites with lower numbers. When the player moves, you can call the [`change_layer`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.change_layer) method of the `LayeredUpdates` group to set the layer of the sprite in the group to the current `rect.bottom` position. Here's a complete example:

```
import random
import pygame as pg


PLAYER_IMG = pg.Surface((30, 50))
PLAYER_IMG.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue1'))
TRIANGLE_IMG = pg.Surface((50, 50), pg.SRCALPHA)
pg.draw.polygon(TRIANGLE_IMG, (240, 120, 0), [(0, 50), (25, 0), (50, 50)])


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = PLAYER_IMG
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        # The sprite will be added to this layer in the LayeredUpdates group.
        self._layer = self.rect.bottom


class Triangle(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = TRIANGLE_IMG
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        # The sprite will be added to this layer in the LayeredUpdates group.
        self._layer = self.rect.bottom


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
    player = Player((50, 80))
    all_sprites.add(player)
    for _ in range(20):
        all_sprites.add(Triangle((random.randrange(600), random.randrange(440))))

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_d]:
            player.rect.x += 5
        if keys[pg.K_a]:
            player.rect.x -= 5
        if keys[pg.K_w]:
            player.rect.y -= 5
        if keys[pg.K_s]:
            player.rect.y += 5
        # If any of the wasd keys are pressed, change the layer.
        if any((keys[pg.K_w], keys[pg.K_a], keys[pg.K_s], keys[pg.K_d])):
            # Set the layer of the player sprite to its rect.bottom position.
            all_sprites.change_layer(player, player.rect.bottom)

        all_sprites.update()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: nice example. I would have used a single class instead of two, but that's just me.

Comment: @sloth, yes, I also considered using only one sprite class, but then thought it would be a little clearer with separate classes. For an actual game, you'd probably need separate classes or subclasses anyway unless you use an entity-component-system.

Comment: @skrx, this is great. This code explained how LayredUpdates() and change_layer method to me nicely. I  find it a big problem tat the pygame documentation site explain the method, well... I just don't get it~